# Deep link into iPhone app without custom scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking

Is there a way to register an iPhone app with a specific URL without a custom scheme? We would like people to be able to post links like this:

https://www.ourcompany.com/OurProduct/DeepLinks?param1=a&&param2=b

So that if the link is clicked on from an iOS device which has our application installed, our application would be opened and have the URL passed to it, and in the case where it was clicked on from a device that doesn't have our application on it, it would simply open the link in a browser.

Ideally we could detect if the user agent is an iOS device and in that case redirect them to the app store.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with Universal Deep Linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal Links are what you want. Unfortunately they only work on iOS 9+, and not everywhere even then ([see here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) for a list). I work with [Branch.io](https://branch.io) and our goal is to help solve this problem!

With Universal Links, when a user opens a link from your website (e.g. https://www.ourcompany.com/OurProduct/DeepLinks?param1=a&&param2=b) in *most* situations (iOS 9+, your app installed, opening the link in an app that supports Universal Links) your app will immediately launch. You can then parse the incoming URL to determine which in-app content to show.

If the user does **not** have your app installed, they will simply end up on your website and you can send them to the App Store. The problem here is after they download the app and open it, the trail is lost. You have no way to know which product they were looking at.

Branch can help close this loop. When a user without your app lands on your website, they'll click a button to download the app. That button will 'fingerprint' this user and then after installing, Branch will return data you can use to immediately display the correct content. You can use our pre-configured [Smart Banner](https://dev.branch.io/features/smart-banner/overview/) or build [your own solution](https://dev.branch.io/features/website-to-app-routing/overview/).

Since you already have a live website on your domain, Branch can't automatically configure the `apple-app-site-association` entitlement file for you. You'll need to handle this yourself. We have a guide for that [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Are you saying that we can implement Deep Linking via Universal Links and use our own domain without making Branch our DNS provider, but have our website redirect to Branch to handle redirects to the AppStore so we can access the deep link params on the first install?

Comment: That is correct! What will actually happen is you'll create a new domain/subdomain (or be assigned one from Branch). The button on your main site page will point to a unique URL at that separate domain, where all the redirect magic will occur. This happens essentially instantly, so the user will never know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at branch.io yet? https://branch.io

It allows you to setup deep links pretty easily (without much of a headache) and covers your requirement as far as I can tell. i.e it features the ability for you to pass parameters with your link and also specify where the user should be directed in the event that they click the link on a device that does/doesn't have the app installed or has been shared on Facebook or somewhere else.

Comment: How can they detect if your application is installed?

Comment: The detection is part of using Universal Links on iOS. Check out Apple's info on them here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: If it's part of Universal Links, why would we need to use branch.io?

Comment: Branch adds the ability to link to the App Store if the app is not installed, which Universal Deep Linking does not support.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: yes, you *could* definitely meet all of those requirements via Universal Links without needing to use the Branch service, but it can be a bit of a headache. We also add some analytics and content tracking functionality to links that might be useful.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Why doesn't Universal Deep Linking not support linking to the App Store. We would simply have a page behind the deep linked url which does a redirect to the app store if the agent is an iOS device.

Comment: @AlexBauer - Question regarding Branch.io. Does Branch.io support using our own domain? The issue is that we would like our deep links to appear to be going to our domain: i.e. https://www.ourcompany.com/OurProduct/DeepLinks?param1=AAA&&param2=BBB

Comment: @bpeikes we sure to! It's actually a very simple process: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/organizing-link-data/guide/#setting-a-custom-link-domain

Comment: @bpeikes I can't answer why it doesn't support linking to the App Store. You'd have to talk to someone at Apple to get that answer. The likely answer is that it was out of scope given the time & resources available.

Comment: @AdamPro13 - You can do your own linking to the App Store on your own web site. There is no way that Apple could have supported it themselves because it would have entailed having every url opened on the phone check with Apple first to see if it was registered.
I was just wondering if there was any technical reason that you can't use Universal Linking, and redirect to the App Store on your own web server.

Comment: @AlexBauer - I looked at the link you posted, but it looks like it requires using branch.io for your DNS.